# Como usar o operador AS com a Library Room?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Não estou conseguindo resgatar a variável `total`, como faço?

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(item_valor) AS total FROM Itens WHERE total =>:data")
Itens getMes(String data);
```

A IDE avisa erro de sintaxe na variável total da Cláusula WHERE.

Minha Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = AppContext.TABLE_ITENS)
public class Itens {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int itemId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_doc")
private String doc;

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_name")
private String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_valor")
private Double valor;
```

Comment: Só com essa explicação não temos como saber aonde está utilizando o código, deveria montar um **exemplo minimo** que explique a situação ...

Comment: `A IDE avisa erro de sintaxe na variável total da Cláusula WHERE.` tem total no apelido do `sum` e no `where` como filtro, não pode dessa forma e também total é o que na sua base de dados? "ou seja, cade o layout dessa tabela???" como podemos ajudar se falta conteúdo para identificar o possível problema !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto na cláusula `WHERE` no seu comando seria `>=` não `=>`

`@Query("SELECT SUM(item_valor) AS total FROM Itens WHERE SUM(item_valor) >= :data")
Itens getMes(String data);`

Dessa maneira deve funcionar corretamente.

O `AS` não funcionaria nesse caso.

Comment: Entendi @Enzo Tiezzi  o correto é usar `WHERE SUM(item_valor)`, obrigado amigo.